# How to order by queryset from another model field?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.9

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Document(models.Model):
   doc_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="DOC")
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name="docs")
   uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


@api_view(["GET"])
def get_items(request):
    # docs__uploaded_at should be from objects having doc_type="DOC" only
    # doc = Document.objects.filter(item=item, doc_type="DOC")
    items = Item.objects.prefetch_related("docs").filter(user=request.user).order_by("docs__uploaded_at")
```

Here I want to order items queryset based on document `uploaded_at` field having `doc_type="DOC"` only.

Comment: An `Item` can have multiple `Document`s, or none at all. How should these be ordered?

Comment: An item can have multiple documents or none also. Should be ordered based on the latest document @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: and what if there is no related document?

Comment: if there's no related document then it will be based on item `created_at` field  like `order_by("DOC_type_docs_uploaded_at", "created_at")`

Comment: So your `Item` has `created_at` field?

Comment: Yes i have but i haven't posted here because i got stuck only with `uploaded_at` so

Answer (score 0):

You could try like the following.

```
items = Item.objects.prefetch_related("docs").filter(user=request.user).filter(docs__doc_type = "DOC").order_by("docs__uploaded_at")
```

Comment: i think it will filter the item queryset as well but i want to order only

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the `uploaded_at` of the latest item with `'DOC'` as `doc_type`:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_items(request):
    items = Item.objects.filter(user=request.user).alias(
        latest_upload=Coalesce(
            Max('docs__uploaded_at', filter=Q(docs__doc_type='DOC')),
            F('created_at')
        )
    ).order_by('-latest_upload')
    # …
```

Here we thus determine the maximum (latest) of the `docs__uploaded_at` for `docs` with `doc_type='DOC'`, and in case there is no item (then `Max(…)` is `NULL`), we fallback on the `created_at` field.

---

> **Note**: [django-1.9](/questions/tagged/django-1.9) is [no longer supported <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) since **April 2017**, you should consider upgrading the Django version.

Comment: does it orders the qs from `latest_upload` following with `item.created_at` ?

Comment: i am getting `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'alias'` error

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I am using django 1.9 version

Comment: @Mark: previous to Django-3.2, you can use `.annotate(..)` instead of `.alias(..)`.

Comment: @Mark: and for Django-1.9 the `filter=...` will not work either. You should **really** upgrade. Django-1.9 is not supported since April **2017**, this is a serious security risk.

Comment: @Mark: these are security risks *reported before the EOL of Django-1.9*: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=10199&product_id=18211&version_id=582749 and here a page of security vulerabilities in general https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/security/ (where they no longer patch Django-1.9 since it is EOL). Some are quite serious like *directory traversal* for uploads and "account hijacks": https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-19844

Comment: filter didn't raise any issue @willem

Comment: @Mark: no, but it does not work: `Max(..)` will simply "swallow" all parameters it does not understand.

Comment: then it can't be done with django 1.9 ?